# jQuery slider setting incorrect ui.values

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a slider that has a `min` value of `Jan 1, 2012` and a `max` value of `Dec 31, 2018`.

When I move the `min` date slider, for some reason the `max` date value gets reset to `Nov 23 2018`.

I think it's similar to the rounding problem here >>> [Jquery UI Slider incorrect max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850921/jquery-ui-slider-incorrect-max-value) but I don't know how to fix a rounding issue with Date.

I have logged a bunch of `console.log`s to see where the `max` date is getting reset. Basically, jQuery slider sets both `min` and `max` values once the slider is clicked. I tried looking under the hood of the [slider API](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) but it wasn't very helpful. I even tried some of the other `Events` to see what their `ui.values` returned to no avail. They all reset the `max` date (incorrectly) to `Nov 23 2018`.

Bottom line: how do I change my code to get the slide `max` date to reflect actual slider?

Code:

```
$("#slider").slider({
  range: true,
  min: new Date("1/1/2012").getTime(),
  max: new Date("12/31/2018").getTime(),
  step: new Date("4/1/2010").getTime() - new Date("1/1/2010").getTime(),
  values: [new Date("1/1/2012").getTime(), new Date("12/31/2018").getTime()],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    // console.log(new Date("12/31/2018").getTime());
    // console.log(ui.values);
    sliderBegDate = new Date(ui.values[0]);
    sliderEndDate = new Date(ui.values[1]);
    $("#dateLabel1").text("From " + formatTime(new Date(ui.values[0])));
    $("#dateLabel2").text(" to " + formatTime(new Date(ui.values[1])));

    updateCharts();
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you include the `formatTime` function if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with your `step` value - Currently you're stepping forwards 3 months at a time, which doesn't divide equally into your `min - max` range, so it's adjusting your `max` to fit the `step`

You could change what your `max` is to fit, or find a `step` amount that works for you - In this demo, I've set the `step` to 4 days and  this works

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  range: true,
  min: new Date("1/1/2012").getTime(),
  max: new Date("12/31/2018").getTime(),
  step: 345600000,
  values: [new Date("1/1/2012").getTime(), new Date("12/31/2018").getTime()],
  
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    sliderBegDate = new Date(ui.values[0]);
    sliderEndDate = new Date(ui.values[1]);
    $("#dateLabel1").text("From " + new Date(ui.values[0]));
    $("#dateLabel2").text(" to " + new Date(ui.values[1]));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>

<div id="dateLabel1">Demo</div>
<div id="dateLabel2">Demo</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Shiny is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913290/10431732) - this has to do with your step value... To demonstrate this, run the code below to see which dates fall in the "step range" you are wanting..

If you want to step by 3 months at a time, it appears the closest to 12/31/2018 (***with*** going over) you can get is 1/1/2019..

```js
let run = true,
  count = 0,
  safetyNet = 10000,
  startDate = new Date("1/1/2012"),
  stopDate = new Date("12/31/2018"),
  monthsToIncrement = 3,
  currentDate = new Date(startDate),
  values = [];

while (currentDate < stopDate && run) {
  count++;
  if (count >= safetyNet) {
    run = false;
  } else {
    values.push(currentDate);
    currentDate = new Date(currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + monthsToIncrement));
  }
}

let lastDate = new Date(values[values.length - 1]);

alert(`Starting at "${startDate.toLocaleDateString()}", and incrementing by "${monthsToIncrement}" months, the closest date we get to "${stopDate.toLocaleDateString()}" is "${lastDate.toLocaleDateString()}"..\r\n\r\nPress OK, and then open your browsers console to view all available values within this range.`);
console.log(values);
```